# Django ajax upload image

Tags: python, ajax, django, post, upload

I try to upload image, using Ajax without django forms.

It not return errors.
Everything it's ok, it save in database "name" and "description" but not save "image" :(

My code:

views.py

```
def add(request):
articles = Article.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
     if request.is_ajax():
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        description = request.POST.get('description')
        icon = request.FILES.get('icon')
        article_new = Article(
            name=name,
            description=description,
            icon=icon
        )
        article_new.save()

return render_to_response('home.html', {'articles':articles}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
 class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    icon = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

html

```
 <form  method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" id="inputName">
      <input type="text" id="inputDescription">
      <input type="file" id="inputFile">
      <button id="submit"  type="submit">Add</button>
  </form>
```

javascript

```
 //For doing AJAX post
 $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#inputName').val();  
    var description = $('#inputDescription').val();
    var icon = $('#inputFile').val();


//This is the Ajax post.Observe carefully. It is nothing but details of where_to_post,what_to_post
$.ajax({
    url : "/add", // the endpoint,commonly same url
    type : "POST", // http method
    data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
    name : name,
    description : description,
    icon: icon
    }, // data sent with the post request
        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
        console.log(json); // another sanity check
        },
        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, did you found the answer, I mean the code. Because I am trying to the same thing and is not working for me. Please post a proper answer if you got one :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is with the Ajax code, you cannot directly send the image via a variable.

To do so, you would have to create FormData and then add the file to it, an example can be found here:
[Send Images Via Ajax](http://webkul.com/blog/send-images-through-ajax/).

Or, simply use the already existing [jquery Ajax Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which does all the hard work for you.

Your choice, hope this helps :)