# django ajax post to unexpect url

Tags: ajax, django

my ajax as follow:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'}
        });
        $("#submit").submit(function () {
            var title = $("#title").val();
            var body = $("#body").val();
            var images = $("#browsefile")[0].files[0];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {title: title, body: body, images: images},
                url: "{% url 'xxxxx' %}",
                success: function (result, statues, xml) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("false");
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

and my urls pattern as follow:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(regex=r'^add/$', view=views.add, name='bbb'),
    url(regex=r'^newBlog/$', view=views.addblog, name='xxxxx'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I except ajax post data to the method addblog, but I get `POST /add/ HTTP/1.1` instead. anyone can told me where i made a mistake, thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your whole `url.py` file?

Comment: @Algorithmatic OK, I re-edit my urls.py file

Comment: I set a breakpoint in my views. when ajax post data, it always enter the method add, but not addblog

Comment: Hmm weird. Can yon you check the value of `url` in the ajax snippet after the page is rendered? You can do that by checking the source code of the html in your browser.

Comment: @Algorithmatic I tried ,the url in page is     url: "/newBlog/"

Comment: does it work if you manually write `newBlog/`

Comment: @Algorithmatic yes, when I direct access the url   http://127.0.0.1:8000/newBlog/    it can access method addblog

Comment: is the form in the `/add` template?

Comment: @Algorithmatic nope, the /add template just redirect to a static html which used to collect the form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `event.preventDefault();` in the submit function to disable the default behavior of the form, which is to follow the action attribute.

```
$("#submit").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var title = $("#title").val();
        var body = $("#body").val();
        var images = $("#browsefile")[0].files[0];
        formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("images", images);
        formdata.append("body", body);
        formdata.append("title", title);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            url: "{% url 'xxxxx' %}",
            success: function (result, statues, xml) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("false");
            }
        })
        return false;
    })
```

**EDIT**:
per comment.

Comment: I solved this problem.I set a fileobj in post data, this is forbidden. And I get a solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866920/django-ajax-upload-image  it told me I need to create a FormData to put fileobj in, and post the FormData as the data.