# How to get data from a Formdata object in my views?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

My AJAX call sends a `FormData` object with an uploaded image data inside it:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#profileImageForm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var image = document.getElementById('id_banner_image').files[0].name;
    form_data.append('file', image);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/change_banner_image/',
        data : {
            form_data: form_data,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
        },
        traditional: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log('Success');
        },
    });
});
```

and I succesfully receive the call in my views:

```
def change_banner_image(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        data = request.POST.get('form_data')
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
        profile.image = data
        profile.save()
        print(data)

    return HttpResponse()
```

`print(data)` prints: `[object FormData]`. So how would I get the uploaded image from this `FormData` object? Which will then be the value of `profile.image` (which is a `FileField`).

Comment: Consider this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866920/django-ajax-upload-image

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're encoding the `FormData` itself, which is incorrect. It is binary data which cannot be encoded in the manner you're attempting.

You instead need to invert the logic to add the CSRF token to the `FormData` you send. You also need to set `processData` and `contentType` to `false` so the binary data is not amended before the request is sent, and also remove the `traditional` property. Try this:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#profileImageForm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var image = document.getElementById('id_banner_image').files[0].name;
    form_data.append('file', image);
    form_data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val());

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/change_banner_image/',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log('Success');
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: `request.POST.get('form_data')` in my views is printing `None`. Any idea why?

Comment: It's because you're sending binary data. I don't know python, but I would guess there's some kind of 'files' collection you need to get instead, eg. `request.FILES.get('file')`

Comment: Your primary key not `'form_data'`, ajax post maybe a `list` but include `dict`, try: `console.log(form_data)` or print whole post on python side.

Comment: `print(form_data)` returns `None` any idea?

Comment: He said *don't* use `form_data` - that's the client side name.

Comment: Yes you're right. `console.log(form_data)` returns a `FormData {}` array. So what would I write to correctly loop over the array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851336/multiple-files-upload-using-same-input-name-in-django

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
data = request.data
```

if you sending file data

```
files = request.FILES
```