# Django & AJAX file upload

Tags: django, ajax

When using `POST` request with AJAX in Django 4.0.1 I can't reach the file from the backend using `request.FILES`. The form used is pretty simple so I can't spot any typos etc.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="snipForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="file" id="multiFiles" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/>
      <button id="upload">Upload</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript:** (sorry for quite a long code sample but I can't shrink it more)

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#upload').on('click', function (event) {
    //Prevent page from reloading
    event.preventDefault()
    var form_data = new FormData();
    // check if there is any file selected
    var ins = document.getElementById('multiFiles').files.length;
    if(ins == 0) {
      $('#msg').html('<span style="color:red">Select at least one file</span>');
      return;
    }
    // add all files
    for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
      form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('multiFiles').files[x]);
    }
    // obtain CSFR token
    csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();

    // set the headers
    headers = {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token};

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/docs/', // point to server-side URL
      dataType: "json",
      ContentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      headers: headers,
      data: form_data,
      success: function (response) { // display success response
        console.log("successssssssssssss")
      },
      error: function (response) {
        console.log("NOPEEEEEE")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def generate(request):
    is_ajax = request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if request.method == 'POST' and is_ajax:
        files = request.FILES.getlist('files[]')
        if files:
            print("file here")
            #do some stuff
        else:
            print("NO FILE AT ALL")
        return JsonResponse({...})
```

Request itself seems to be working `console.log('sucessss')` is visible after request is completed. Django however has no access to the file. The data with stored file is saved in the `form_data` but as far as I know we can reach files through mentioned `request.FILES['name_of_the_input']`.

What might be the cause?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31871699/14509153

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't clarify much - I already used `new FormData()` so the problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing a file upload(with FormData) with $.ajax, you must set contentType and processData to false.
Otherwise jQuery will try to convert you FormData object to a string and set the content type of the request to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` which is wrong.
The correct content type is multipart/formdata and will be set automatically.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/docs/', // point to server-side URL
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  headers: headers,
  data: form_data,
  success: function (response) { // display success response
    console.log("successssssssssssss")
  },
  error: function (response) {
    console.log("NOPEEEEEE")
  }
});
```

Comment: This resolved all issues. Thank you very much